# PrimeFaces UploadedFile afax sizelimit from modal dialog

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have the requirement to get uploaded file from modal dialog. So I managed to do so with primeFaces `fileUpload` component with simple non-ajax mode:

```
<p:dialog id="dlg" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)"
          header="#{messages['pages.dlg']}" closeOnEscape="true">
    <h:form id="dlgForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Some business data -->
        <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" mode="simple"/>
        <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" action="#{bean.save}" update="messages" ajax="false"
            partialSubmit="dlgForm"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

When `save` method invoked from bean I have service method running with business logic. Now I get the new requirement: limit the file size to 5 MB. But when I trying to use `sizeLimit` attribute on `fileUpload` component - I get nothing happens. The reason is the validation is on the client side but with disabled `ajax` it is not possible to validate.

I tried to take an `advanced` mode, but get several problems:

1. The `uploadedFile` on the bean is `requestScoped` - so I can't get the data when `save` button invoked. I can save it only in `fileUploadListener` - but there comes the problem: I need another business data to be saved as part of that process. The uploaded file is part of the information provided by user. I can't just invoke saving file without that data.
2. When file is getting uploaded with preview (if it is image file) when `upload` is pressed - the preview will dissapear immediatily after file will be uploaded. How can I tell him to stay on that bottom field of `advanced` mode from `fileUpload` component? And get saved on the server-side only when `save` button pressed?

So question is: how can I use `advanced` component type within such dialog? I'm running with PrimeFaces 6.0, JSF 2.2 (mojara).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution and it is very simple. I just need to save uploaded file on the private field of bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    @EJB
    private SomeService service;

    private BusinessObjectDTO objectDTO; // DTO with business data from dialog form
    private byte[] fileData;
    private String fileName;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        fileData = JSFHelper.getFileData(uploadedFile);
        fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
    }

    // Invoked when save is called from dialog
    public void save() {
        service.save(objectDTO, fileData, fileName);
        // add info message
    }
}
```

And then I can get `oncomplete` working with showing uploaded file preview in another component.

Comment: But this **also** is a viewscoped bean, not a requestscoped one as you stated in your question! And I don't see you actually saving it somewhere (only the name) unless that hapens in your JSFHelper. Then it would be better to include that code inline in this method.

Comment: @Kukeltje Save happens on `save` method when button from dialog pressed. JSFHelper is used only for getting bytes from `UploadedFile` instance.

Comment: sorry, I missed a small part, my bad. but you still **also** changed the scope, didn't you?